# Função JavaScript Cannot read property 'value' of null

Tags: javascript

Criei uma função em javascript, e ela funciona quando o campo txtDiaVencimento é preenchido, porém nem sempre esse campo irá ser preenchido, quando ele não é preenchido ele me retorna o seguinte erro:

> Cannot read property 'value' of null

Segue um pedaço do código:

```
if (document.getElementById("<%= txtDiaVencimento.ClientID %>").value != null) {
    var data = document.getElementById("<%= txtDataInicio.ClientID %>").value;
    var data_inicio = data.substring(0, data.indexOf("/"));
    var dia_vencimento = document.getElementById("<%= txtDiaVencimento.ClientID %>").value;
}
```

Eu tento verificar se ele é nulo, para que não entre na função, porém mesmo assim ele retorna o erro. E ele não continua o resto da função. O erro é sempre no `document.getElementById("<%= txtDiaVencimento.ClientID %>").value`quando ele está vazio, pois ou é preenchido o txtDiaVencimento ou o  txtDiaFim.

Comment: Você deve verificar se o `getElementById` é nulo, não seu valor. Isto é, retire o `.value` que está na condição do `if`.

Comment: Mariana, você pode me tirar uma dúvida? No post você diz: "_ela funciona quando o campo txtDiaVencimento é preenchido_", isso quer dizer que o campo **tem algum valor** ou que ele **foi criado visualmente**?

Comment: Posso tirar sim, é porque tem uma condição, ou ele é preenchido ou o campo txtDataFim, mas dessa forma que você me auxiliou, ele entra no if corretamente, e não da o problema, e está funcionando da forma que deveria. Não sei se fui clara.

Comment: @marianac_costa, quando você não preenche `txtDiaVencimento`, ele entra no if? se sim, isso é um problema? se possível edite sua pergunta com o html em questão. (pode por um `console.log('entrou');` , dentro do if para verificar).

Comment: Se eu não preenche ele não entra, já ficou resolvido, a resposta me ajudou.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O certo é verificar se o retorno `getElementById` é nulo e não o valor dele.

```
if (document.getElementById("<%= txtDiaVencimento.ClientID %>") != null) {
    var data = document.getElementById("<%= txtDataInicio.ClientID %>").value;
    var data_inicio = data.substring(0, data.indexOf("/"));
    var dia_vencimento = document.getElementById("<%= txtDiaVencimento.ClientID %>").value;
}
```

Comment: Funcionou certinho na minha função, eu ainda estou apanhando bastante de javascript, rs. Obrigado.