# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null

Tags: javascript

Estou com uma função em JavaScript e ela está me retornando o seguinte erro:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null

```
if (parseInt(data_inicio) < parseInt(dia_vencimento)) {

  document.getElementById("<%= checkPorp.ClientID %>").checked = true;
  document.getElementById("<%= checkPorp.ClientID %>").style.visibility = "visible";
  document.getElementById("<%= lbValorPor.ClientID %>").style.visibility = "visible";
  document.getElementById("<%= Label20.ClientID %>").style.visibility = "visible";

  var valor = document.getElementById("<%= txtValorServico.ClientID %>").value;
  valor = valor.replace(",", ".");
  var dias = valor / 30;
  var vencimento = dia_vencimento;
  var porpocional = data_inicio - vencimento;
  var qtd = porpocional * dias;
  var resultado = valor - qtd;

  var labe1 = document.getElementById('lbValorPor');
  labe1.innerHTML = resultado.toFixed(2);

  document.getElementById("<%= txtpropor.ClientID %>").value = resultado;
  document.getElementById("<%= lbValorPor.ClientID %>").value = resultado;

}
```

Ele dá erro nesta linha:

> `document.getElementById("<%= txtpropor.ClientID %>").value = resultado;`

Só que no *debugger* do código, o resultado tem valor, não sei porque ele me retorna este erro.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtpropor" runat="server" Enabled="True" ViewStateMode="Enabled" AutoPostBack="False" Visible="False"></asp:TextBox>
```

Tentei todos as dicas informadas na pergunta: [link pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/249754/fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-javascript-cannot-read-property-value-of-null), porém nenhuma resolveu o meu problema.

Comment: Porque o `id` dado por `<%= txtpropor.ClientID %>` não existe na página

Comment: Ele existe, está na mesma página html.

Comment: Eu usei todas as dicas dessa pergunta, porém nenhuma me ajudou.

Comment: Então elabore um [mcve] postando o código JS gerado pela aplicação, mostrando qual é o valor de `txtpropor.ClientID`.

Comment: Qual o HTML gerado pelo txtpropor? e se voce der `console.log(<%= txtpropor.ClientID %>)` o Id eh identico ao do HTML gerado?

Comment: Sim, mas ele me retorna este erro, isso pq o resultado tem valor, não sei porque ele da o erro na hora de passar o valor para txtpropor.

Comment: @LucasCosta o engraçado, que se eu comentar essa linha do txtpropor, o código funciona como deveria funcionar, só q eu preciso passar o valor para esse txt,só que ele informa este erro.

Comment: Ele esta dando esse erro porque tem erro em algum lugar. Se quiser podemos continuar no chat @marianac_costa

Comment: @LucasCosta podemos sim, se vc puder me ajudar

Comment: @LucasCosta eu mudei a linha para assim:  $("#txtpropor").val(resultado); e funcionou, só que agora da o mesmo erro, em uma outra, q passa o valor igual estava sendo passado antes, essa é uma prática boa ? Eu sou novata ainda na área javascript e jquery. Obrigado.